# Gird view or list view is better in wpf for floor mapping

Tags: c#, wpf, xamarin

I am doing one project where I want display the office floor with two thousnads seats which will be user interactive and will be inside the wpf Viewport2DVisual3D and  all the seats(cells) will have stack panel  with image which is bound with data base items from table) I will be using scroller and zoomer  for moving in the screen.My question is whetehr I have to use Grid view or List view(with conrol templates) for this purpose considering the performance and maintenance or is there any other option to do this. I am new to WPF please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

A Canvas control can be used to place items with arbitrary pixel coordinates, maybe that could be usefull?

```
<Canvas>
    <Stackpanel Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Right="10"></Stackpanel>
    <Stackpanel Canvas.Left="20" Canvas.Right="20"></Stackpanel>
</Canvas>
```